# Why the sendMailConfirmation method does not send a signedURL to the user?

Tags: php, symfony5

By using Symfony 5 and after user registration, the system should send an automatic email to the user to activate a signed URL. In EmailVerifer.php, the sendMailConfirmation method does not recognize the getId and getEmail methods. However after registration the confirmation email is anyway sent by the system to the user but without a signed URL to activate it. I think the issue is related to the implementation of serialization and deserialization methods in user class, as it worked before Serialization implementation. I'm trying to implement serializable methods in EmailVerifier class but it doesn't work. Thanks for the help.

```html
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Mime\TemplatedEmail;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Mailer\MailerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use SymfonyCasts\Bundle\VerifyEmail\Exception\VerifyEmailExceptionInterface;
use SymfonyCasts\Bundle\VerifyEmail\VerifyEmailHelperInterface;

class EmailVerifier
{
    private $verifyEmailHelper;
    private $mailer;
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(VerifyEmailHelperInterface $helper, MailerInterface $mailer, EntityManagerInterface $manager)
    {
        $this->verifyEmailHelper = $helper;
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->entityManager = $manager;
    }

    public function sendEmailConfirmation(string $verifyEmailRouteName, UserInterface $user, TemplatedEmail $email): void
    {
        $signatureComponents = $this->verifyEmailHelper->generateSignature(
            $verifyEmailRouteName,
            $user->getId(),
            $user->getEmail()
        );

        $context = $email->getContext();
        $context['signedUrl'] = $signatureComponents->getSignedUrl();
        $context['expiresAtMessageKey'] = $signatureComponents->getExpirationMessageKey();
        $context['expiresAtMessageData'] = $signatureComponents->getExpirationMessageData();

        $email->context($context);

        $this->mailer->send($email);
    }

    /**
     * @throws VerifyEmailExceptionInterface
     */
    public function handleEmailConfirmation(Request $request, UserInterface $user): void
    {
        $this->verifyEmailHelper->validateEmailConfirmation($request->getUri(), $user->getId(), $user->getEmail());

        $user->setIsVerified(true);

        $this->entityManager->persist($user);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: So you're saying there is something going wrong with serialization, but your code does not show anything that has to do with that... Can you please update your question so that your code shows the code that isn't working like you would like it to?

Comment: Please share more details. The given code looks pretty simple, and stepping through using XDebug should not be too hard

Answer (score -1):

try this command
$ php bin/console messenger:consume async

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What makes you think that the messenger is involved here? The class itself does not use the bus

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34846505)